# Почему Enter string: выводится 2 раза в одной строке? c++

Tags: c++, строки

Пишу лабораторную. Возникла проблема, что при выводе в консоль записи "Enter a string:", она выводилась ещё один раз на этой же строке. Подскажите, в чём проблема и как это пофиксить?
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n;
    cout << "Enter N number: "; // Вводим кол-во строк
    cin >> n;
    vector <string> v; // Инициализируем строковый вектор
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        string str; // Объявляем строку
        cout << "Enter string: "; // Вводим строку 
        getline(cin, str); // Записываем строку
        string new_s; // Объявляем новую строку

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
        {
            if (str[j] != ' ') // Если str[j] не пробел (т.к. пробел - это пробел), то
            {
                new_s += char(int(str[j] + 1));
            }
            else // Если str[j] - пробел, то просто добавляем пробел
            {
                new_s += ' ';
            }
        }
        v.push_back(new_s); // Расшифрованную строку в массив
    }

    int v_len = v.size(); // Узнаём размер массива

    for (int i = 0; i < v_len; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << endl; // Выводим расшифрованные строки
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter N number: 2
Enter string: Enter string: love cats
Enter string: love cats

mpwf dbut
mpwf dbut
```

Comment: Это же в цикле у Вас :) вот и выводится

Comment: @Виктор извиняюсь за некорректность, добавил output

Comment: Замените getline(cin, str); на  cin >> str;

Comment: @Виктор И как вы через `>>` собираетесь считывать `love cats`?

Comment: тогда так: cin >> n;
   cin.clear();                          
    cin.sync ();